# Parquet decoding exception while reading parquet files over spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I've generated parquet files using append data mode over spark. But while reading those files, throwing parquet decode exceptions.

I'm already using merge-schema option, but the problem I'm facing is with files part of some partitions. Other partitions are not throwing any kind of exception.

```
df = spark.read.parquet("s3://bucket/folder/date=<>/")
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecutionException: Encounter error while reading parquet files. One possible cause: Parquet column cannot be converted in the corresponding files. Details:
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:193)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:101)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException: Can not read value at 0 in block -1 in file s3://bucket/key/date=<>/part-00028-625e653b-c000.snappy.parquet
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:251)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(ParquetRecordReader.java:207)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:181)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Expected instance of group converter but got "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRowConverter$ParquetStringConverter"
        at org.apache.parquet.io.api.Converter.asGroupConverter(Converter.java:34)
        at org.apache.parquet.io.RecordReaderImplementation.<init>(RecordReaderImplementation.java:267)
        at org.apache.parquet.io.MessageColumnIO$1.visit(MessageColumnIO.java:147)
        at org.apache.parquet.io.MessageColumnIO$1.visit(MessageColumnIO.java:109)
        at org.apache.parquet.filter2.compat.FilterCompat$NoOpFilter.accept(FilterCompat.java:165)
        at org.apache.parquet.io.MessageColumnIO.getRecordReader(MessageColumnIO.java:109)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.checkRead(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:137)
        at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:222)
        ... 25 more
```

Reading the mentioned file, doesn't throw any exception. But reading all the files under folder, throw exception wrt a single file. There is other data set in similar folders, but that doesn't threw any exceptions.
I'm not able to understand the real cause for this error, and is there any option or way to fix this ?

Comment: Did numerical (or data types overall) change from one append to another?

Is the issue when you load 
   1 s3://bucket/folder/date=04092019/ (meaning you can load the part files only)
   2 s3://bucket/folder/ (meaning you can all the files within any of the date but not two at the same time)